# dehydrated cronjob - HTTP-01 challenge invalid

Tags: webserver, nginx

So I have set up a dehydrated cron job to renew the certs for a bunch of domains I manage. Well a friend helped to do it.

It has worked like a charm when first run. But then, few months later, in order to renew the certs it failed.

I have an "ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid)"

What I know is that it trying to see if I own the domain name, so it sends a challenge to an address WELLKNOWN variable, which is under "/var/www/dehydrated" (if I am not mistaken).

What I don't know is that why the challenge is invalid for some obscure reasons, and I hope it is not related to the way the webserver is configured. I am using Nginx.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that your looking in the wrong direction...

Challenge is used to check correct DNS Mapping, so you have to check that the domains related to the certs are on the correct IP (A or CNAME records).

So, the challenge (HTTP) with letsencrypt for example, is tryin to exchange information with *Webserver running under WELLKNOWN  **NOT variable** but **DNS record**.

If your domain is sub.mydomain.com your nginx must be configured to answer to sub.mydomain.com throught DNS protocol and documentroot like /var/www/dehydrated must be writable to achieve the challenge.